# Asa5508 NAT two internal IPs

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

Hello I have a Cisco asa5508 and I want to NAT 2 internal IP's to 2 public IP's that I have.Each IP on its own.

Currently I have NatPool and it's working either with the one IP or with the other.

Is it possible to make static NAT for each set of IP's?  Lets say 10.x.x.101 to 200.x.x.201 and 10.x.x.102 to 200.x.x.202?

What options do I have? Can you advise with the commands?

Thanx in advance.

Here some config

```
show xlate
3 in use, 105 most used
Flags: D - DNS, e - extended, I - identity, i - dynamic, r - portmap,
       s - static, T - twice, N - net-to-net
NAT from outside:151.x.x.13 to DMZ:10.x.x.13
    flags s idle 137:57:35 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from outside:151.x.x.14 to DMZ:10.x.x.14
    flags s idle 137:57:35 timeout 0:00:00

NAT from DMZ:10.x.x.13 to outside:151.x.x.13 flags i idle 0:00:04 timeout 3:00:00
show running-config nat
object network PubIP
 nat (outside,DMZ) static 10.x.x.14
object network PubIP2
 nat (outside,DMZ) static 10.x.x.13
object network DMZ-LAN
 nat (DMZ,outside) dynamic NatPool


show runn object
object network PubIP
 host 151.x.x.14
object network IP
 host 10.x.x.14
object network PubIP2
 host 151.x.x.13
object network IP.13
 host 10.x.x.13
object network NatPool
 range 151.x.x.13 151.x.x.14
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please show us what you have configured so far, edit your question and add relevant pieces of configuration using the preformatted text option using `{` and `}`.

Comment: Please include your full configuration.

Comment: Here is some config's

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make static nat for each set of ip's?

Yes.

```
static (inside,outside) 200.x.x.201 10.x.x.101 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) 200.x.x.202 10.x.x.102 netmask 255.255.255.255
```